# Remove rejected edit from my record

Tags: support

I was rolling back vandalism and the vandal [rejected one of my edits](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/454597). That is my only rejected edit and I don't want it on my record. Please remove that rejection from the database.

Correction:

Something I don't understand happened with [this edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/454605) as well. So I have two rejected edits that I'm asking be removed.

Comment: Uh... why would you want this? Having a rejected edit on your history is not a shame or something.

Comment: Actually, when you see someone doing this (especially to multiple posts), you should be flagging for a moderator, not trying to deal with the vandalism on your own.

Answer (score 9):

You're using the wrong moderation option.

If you choose to suggest an edit or rollback an edit the outcome of that suggestion is logged in your profile, whether you like it or not. I don't think removal is possible or should be possible for that matter.

This is specially true if OP's are vandalizing their own posts. Rolling back is in such cases better left to users with edit privileges as their edits don't go into the queue.

In case of users vandalizing their posts and you don't have the edit privilege use a custom moderator flag and explain what is going on and what you think should happen (roll back, delete, lock).